# Change Javascript to Update Panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

I have JavaScript that works excellently but I need to change it to Update Panel and I can't get it to still work properly.

What I want it to do is if it selects 1 in the first dropdown, pick c in the second dropdown.

I am using asp.net vb. I appreciate all the help!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function NumbersDropDownList_OnChange() {
            var numbersDropDownList = document.getElementById("numbersDropDownList");
            if (numbersDropDownList.options[numbersDropDownList.selectedIndex].text=="1") {
                document.getElementById("lettersDropDownList").selectedIndex = 2;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="numbersDropDownList" onchange="NumbersDropDownList_OnChange()" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="lettersDropDownList" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>a</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>b</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>c</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which control do you want to wrap with updatepanel?

Comment: howHearWhere.ascx  Thank you!

Comment: well, that control is not being used in the code shown above...

Comment: When I added it to the control the Javascript stopped working so I just pasted what was working.  Sorry I'm really new to all of this so if you can help and you need any more info from me please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnllettersDropDownList" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="numbersDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" >1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" >2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3" >3</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="lettersDropDownList" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" >a</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" >b</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3" >c</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>        
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Protected Sub numbersDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles numbersDropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged
        if numbersDropDownList.selectedvalue=2 then
          lettersDropDownList.selectedvalue=3
        end if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling your controls incorrectly from the javascript.  You are just "getting lucky" that your current script works, simply because your lists are in the base level of the form.

Correct your script as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function NumbersDropDownList_OnChange() {
        var numbersDropDownList = document.getElementById('<%= numbersDropDownList.ClientID %>');
        if (numbersDropDownList.options[numbersDropDownList.selectedIndex].text=="1") {
            document.getElementById('<%= lettersDropDownList.ClientID %>').selectedIndex = 2;
        }
    }
</script>
```